# Newtonsoft JSON deserialize to type from list

Tags: c#, json, reflection, json.net

I have created a list of types like this:

```
var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var referencedAssemblies = executingAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
var assembly = referencedAssemblies.Single(x => x.Name.Equals("X.Y.Z"));
var messagesAssembly = Assembly.Load(assembly);
var types = messagesAssembly.GetTypes();
var selectedTypes = from t in types
                    where t.Namespace.Contains("X.Y.Z.K")
                    select t;
```

and I need to convert some json data into one of these types. How do I figure out which one is the correct one?

I have tried the following:

```
var jsonData = File.ReadAllText(filePair.FullPath);
foreach(var type in selectedTypes)
{
     var correctObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData, type);
}
```

Which just converts it to the first type in the list
I have also tried with the template method

```
var jsonData = File.ReadAllText(filePair.FullPath);
foreach(var type in selectedTypes)
{
     var correctObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<type>(jsonData);
}
```

Which "Cannot resolve symbol 'type'.

Is it possible to convert it to a the correct type in selectedTypes?

Comment: I had something like this a while back, had a Json file with different elements like TextField and Switch etc. I tried to use the [CustomCreationConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm) but ended up using the [JsonConverter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)

Comment: Show us the serialization code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using ".NET's fastest JSOn Serializer by ServiceStack".
It has a method ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(string value, Type type) which worked perfectly.